# Attempting to use UI pointer in QT in a derived class

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, inheritance

I am having trouble trying to use the UI pointer in a different class in QT and I think the problem is I don't understand how the UI pointer is created.

First the UI pointer is declared here in neutropenia_main.h

```
    namespace Ui {
class Neutropenia_Main;
}

class Neutropenia_Main : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Neutropenia_Main(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Neutropenia_Main();

    Ui::Neutropenia_Main *ui;
```

And then it is defined here in Neutropenia_main.cpp

```
Neutropenia_Main::Neutropenia_Main(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Neutropenia_Main)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Now I have an abstract class called classification_interface.h that inherits Neutropenia_main.h.  And I am working on 1 of 9 derived classes that inherits classification_interface.  In the derived class ts_classifier.cpp, I am trying to use ui like so:

```
    void ts_classifier::output(int classification)
{
    if (classification == 1)
    {
        ui -> Classification_Table ->setItem(i,1,new QTableWidgetItem("At Risk"));
    }else if(classification == 0) {
        ui -> Classification_Table -> setItem(i,1,new QTableWidgetItem("Not At Risk"));
    }else {
        ui -> Classification_Table -> setItem(i,1,new QTableWidgetItem("Inconclusive"));
    }
}
```

The use of ui in the class creates the following error :
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Neutropenia_Application\ts_classifier.cpp:8: error: C2027: use of undefined type 'Ui::Neutropenia_Main'

So why is there two declarations of Neutropenia_Main, one in the namespace ui and one as a stand alone.  Why is the ui pointer of type UI:Neutropenia_main.  And how can I use the ui pointer in derived classes.

Comment: Incomplete code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how is it incomplete.  I have showed where it is declared, where it is defined and how I am trying to use it.

Comment: You show us where **you think** the problem might be located. You pick one function from your a class. For me it is extremely unpleasant to have only a peephole view on your code. ts_classifier? How does the constructor look like? What do you include? You say 'derived' class. I know what a derived class is. Do you? Perhaps. But how do I know  that you know? Sometimes absolute beginners post here. Above you show us pieces of two classes. Would it be too difficult to show us the whole of those classes? Cannot be that much code.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean.  I was about to edit the question one I noticed there was a another ui_class that I missed and was not included in my classification_interface base class.   I will take your above comment to heart and apply it to the next question I ask.  Thanks @Greenflow.

Comment: You need to include the ui_something.h header, generated by uic (and put into your build dir), something like "#include "ui_neutropenia_main.h". Exact naming depends on the name you assigned to the top level widget in the .ui file. As for accessing it from other classes: I wouldn't do that, better add wrappers as need to the non-namespaced Neutropenia_main.